# Cannot install openai with micropip

Tags: pyodide

Unable to install openAI in Pyodide

I run the following but get the error: Couldn't find a pure Python 3 wheel for 'openai'

```
import micropip
await micropip.install('openai')
```

Comment: Pyscript also uses pyodide and so some of the excellent documentation there helps you understand limitations in the current WASM offerings. See ['What packages can I use? Can I use anything from PyPI?' at the FAQ for pyscript](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/reference/faq.html#what-packages-can-i-use-can-i-use-anything-from-pypi). Related to what is there [the pyodide documentation 'wasm-constraints.html' page](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/wasm-constraints.html) covers removed and not working modules at the bottom at present.

Comment: There is a work in progress issue on it in https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide/issues/3588

Answer (score 0):

As of 04.09.23 Pyodide doesn't support the OpenAI module, however you can speed up it being added by adding more activity to this issue:
https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide/issues/3588

Pyodide is fairly new so some stuff like this is expected. I found a workaround by sending an XML request to OpenAI directly (aka https://api.openai.com/v1/completions) but as of today morning it just stopped working, seemingly on the side of OpenAI since I made no change and old versions of my code functional in the past don't work either.

This only sends a request to the completions on that specific link which is used for older models, I'm not excluding that there isn't a modern version of it for newer GPT models thought, although waiting for it to be added to pyodide or using JavaScript for it might be the best option for you atleast for the time being.